# Authentication failed on the remote side (the stream might still be available for additional authentication attempts)

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an application that uses WCF between client and server, but, when i try to run my app, it gives me this exeception. One solution that i found was conect a direct cable between the two machines(not using the router nor switch).

Here's my client config :

```
<netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IOperacao" closeTimeout="00:15:00"
      openTimeout="00:15:00" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00"
      transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
      hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="21474836470"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="1000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
        enabled="false" />
      <!--<security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>-->
      <security mode="None"></security>
    </binding>
    <!--<binding name="NetTcpBinding_IOperacao1">
      <security>
        <transport protectionLevel="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>-->
  </netTcpBinding>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting your error in conjunction with another error. I thought it was the firewall or something blocking traffic on my machine when calling the wcf service.

**In the end it was caused by not setting the username and password correctly after creating the client.** See my solution in this other post for details on how to fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60010234/151325